Acceder a un método de un objeto en Java Script guardado en un array
intento acceder al método alquilar() de instancias de mi objeto Película() almacenadas en un array que he llamado miBiblioteca pero me da un error cuando lo intento. Todo forma parte de una pequeña web que crea instancias del objeto Película, las almacena en dicho arreglo y luego deberia dejar alquilarlas, devolverlas o ver el ultimoAlquiler. Creo que podría ser algún error de sintaxis pero no soy capaz de identificarlo.
El siquiente método se ejecuta al pulsar el boton de alquilar


 function alquilarPelicula(){
            //Leer el valor seleccionado, buscarlo en miBiblioteca y llamar al método alquilar del objeto
            var selected = document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
            var nombreUsuario = document.getElementById("nombreUsuario").value;

            //Llamo al método alquilar y le paso el nuevo nombre de usuario
            miBiblioteca[selected].value.alquilar(nombreUsuario);
           
        }



Y a continuación el constuctor del objeto Película


function Pelicula(titulo, año, duracion, precioAlquiler) {
            this.titulo = titulo;
            this.año = año;
            this.duracion = duracion;
            this.precioAlquiler = precioAlquiler;
            this.alquilada = false;
            this.ultimoUsuario = ""; 

            function alquilar(ultimoUsuario){
                if(!this.alquilada){
                    this.alquilada = true;
                    this.ultimoUsuario = ultimoUsuario;
                    alert("La película ha sido alquilada con éxito");
                }else{
                    alert(this.titulo + " está alquilada");
                }
            };

            function devolver(){...};

            function ultimoAlquiler(){...};

        }



El resto sería el array y la función que utilizo para guardar las instancias en el


var miBiblioteca = [];

        //Creando nueva instancia de Pelicula()
        function guardar() {
            var peli = new Pelicula( 
                document.getElementById("titulo").value,
                document.getElementById("año").value,
                document.getElementById("duracion").value,
                document.getElementById("precioAlquiler").value
            )
            //Añado la nueva instancia a miBiblioteca
            miBiblioteca.push(peli);
            //Muestro la película en el select
            var option = new Option(peli.titulo, peli);
            document.getElementById("mySelect").appendChild(option);
            console.log(peli);
            console.log(miBiblioteca);
            alert("Peli guardada!!");
        }




Si en tu array estás guardando objetos tipo Pelicula, por qué luego intentas acceder al atributo value del array??? No tiene sentido ninguno, lo que has metido en el array es un objeto pelicula, no un objeto que contiene el objeto pelicula en un atributo value.... cambia miBiblioteca[selected].value.alquilar(nombreUsuario); por miBiblioteca[selected].alquilar(nombreUsuario); y ya está. No estás leyendo un input que necesites ver su value, es un array que literalmente acabas de montar tú mismo y guardarle directamente los objetos de pelicula.

Si, no me había dado cuenta de que lo había dejado así al final. Inicialmente lo hice como me dices pero no funcionaba y comencé a hacer cambios por todos lados a ver de que manera funcionaba( aunque este último tampoco tenía mucho sentido)
